# Java doesn't read excel files on Linux (with Apache POI)

Tags: java, linux, apache-poi, import-from-excel

I'm using Apache POI to read an Excel file that I upload to my system. It works well on Windows but doesn't work on Linux Platform.

```
  File file=null;
    List<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

       FileInputStream fileIS = null;
       List<LoanClosureDebit> closeFacilityDebitList = new ArrayList<LoanClosureDebit>();
       Iterator<Row> rowIterator;
       String webTempPath = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/userImages/");

       System.out.println("***********getting path********"+webTempPath);
       file=getFile(request.getSession().getId()+".xlsx",webTempPath);
       if(!file.exists()){
           //for open office calc
           file = getFile(request.getSession().getId()+".xls",webTempPath);                                                                                                                                                                             
           fileIS = new FileInputStream(file);
           POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(fileIS);
           HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
           HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
           rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
       }else{
           //for ms excel
           fileIS = new FileInputStream(file);
           XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileIS);

           //Get first sheet from the workbook
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            rowIterator= sheet.iterator();
       }
       JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
       //Iterate through each rows from first sheet
       while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
           JSONArray objArray = new JSONArray();
           Row row = rowIterator.next();
}
```

In Linux the code works Until the while Statement and no more.
The file gets uploaded to the server too. (I use Tomcat) I'm not sure whether I should add any extra jars or any other configurations are needed. Could it be a problem with permissions?  I  have already added the jar files stated below 
poi-3.9-20121203.jar

poi-ooxml-3.9-20121203.jar

poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9-20121203.jar

dom4j-1.6.1.jar

xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar

Comment: Are u getting any exception?

Comment: What is the value of this thing - `request.getSession().getId()+".xls"` and what is `getFile` method. I am pretty sure that this has nothing to with Apache Poi.

Comment: Describe the error please, any exception.. or the problem is that you get no data?

Comment: There is No error. When I debug, It doesn't execute after the while command @JunedAhsan

Comment: Have you inspected *rowIterator* object?

Comment: Why are you using an old version of Apache POI? (3.9 is over 2 years old, as the dates in the jar file show you!)